# Xamarin (UWP): System.NullReferenceException if the property "ImageSource" of Button is set

Tags: forms, xamarin, uwp

I am using Xamarin.Forms4.7.0.1080 to develop a UWP application and i met a System.NullReferenceException if the property "ImageSource" of Button is set.
The Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
    at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.ButtonRenderer.<UpdateContent>d__19.MoveNext()
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0(Object state)
    at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContextBase.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```

The Button in xaml:

```
<Button
    Padding="0"
    BackgroundColor="#FFC0E0F4"
    BorderWidth="0"
    CornerRadius="0"
    ImageSource="{Binding IconIndex,Converter={StaticResource ResourceConverter}}"
    IconPosition="Top"
    Text="{Binding Name}"
    TextColor="#FF014C7A" />
```

I found this https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1423, but i still can not solve my problem. please help me.

Comment: If you convert back to previous version such as `V4.6.0.1073` , Is that worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating [Xamarin.Forms](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin/xamarin-forms) to version [4.8.0.1451](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.8/4.8.0-sr2), this Exception never appeared again.